# Сохранить несколько значений в одну переменную с типом number (Побитовые операторы)

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно решить такую задачу, у меня есть несколько переменных:

```
const area = 547030;
const people = 63182000;
const worked = true; // или число 1
const retired = false; // или число 0
```

Мне нужно сохранить эту информации в одну переменную с названием допустим `result` (в виде целого числа с типом `number`).
Чтобы я потом мог из этого числа получить те значение, которые я туда сохранял, а именно:

```
area, // 547030
people, // 63182000
worked, // true или число 1
retired // false или число 0
```

Я так понял здесь нужно использовать Побитовые операторы и Формат 32-битного целого числа. Только мне не ясно, как мне сохранить в одну переменю столько информации, чтобы потом можно было ее прочитать и найти те значение, которые я туда сохранил.

Comment: Для этого существуют массивы , либо можно использовать объекты js

Comment: Я знаю, но мне нужно решить эту задачу именно таким способом

Comment: Тогда это вопрос для специалиста по js

Comment: 547030 - минимум 20 бит. 63182000 - минимум 28 бит. true/false - по 1 биту. Всего - 50 бит. Т.е. нужно 64-битное целое. А поскольку Javascript все числа представляет как 64-битные с плавающей точкой, всё очень грустно.

Comment: А если цифры будут меньше, допустим 5423 это - 13 бит и 7854 тоже 13 бит, также true/false - по 1 биту. Всего 28 бит. Как можно будет решить эту задачу?

Comment: 32-битные целые в формате 64-битного с плавающей точкой представимы точно (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 2^53-1 = 9007199254740991). И с ними можно выполнять побитовые логические операции (или просто целочисленные деление/остаток). В принципе если за 52 бита не выскакиваете - то и с исходными прокатит...

Comment: что-то вроде такого: `var res = ((((((area<<bitforpeople)|people)<<1)|worked)<<1)|retired)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подумаешь прошло полгода и меня сегодня утром осенило, что тут и без побитовых операций можно обойтись, вообщем вот такой код получился:

```js
function Binary() {
  this.encode = function(data) {
    let number = "";
    let map = {}
    for (var d in data) {
      number += data[d].toString(2)
      map[d] = data[d].toString(2).length;
    }
    
    return [parseInt(number,2),map];
  }
  
  this.decode_map = function(number,map,name) {
    let length;
    let start = 0;
    for(let key in map) {
      if(key === name) {
        length = map[key];
        break;
      }
      start += map[key]
    }
    return this.decode(number,start,start+length);
  }
  
  this.decode = function(number,start,end) {
    return parseInt((number.toString(2).slice(start,end)),2);
  }
}

const data = {
 area : 547030,
 people : 63182000,
 worked : 1,
 retired : 0,
}

const $b = new Binary()

let [num,map] = $b.encode(data);
console.log(num);
console.log(map);
console.log("area " + $b.decode_map(num,map,'area'));
console.log("people " + $b.decode_map(num,map,'people'));
console.log("worked " + $b.decode_map(num,map,'worked'));
console.log("retired " + $b.decode_map(num,map,'retired'));
```

`encode` - получает объект `ключ: число` и сливает все числа в одно, переводя в двоичный код, затем возвращая полученное число в 10-ом формате. Также эта функция возвращает карту, в которой указана длина каждого числа в двоичной системе и ее его ключ, это нужно для декодирования.

`encode_map` - передаем число, карту и ключ тех данных, что хотим получить.

`encode` - в довесок, если нужно вырезать из числа часть двоичного представления, без всяких карт